# Is there a way to discover if a javascript 6 class defines its own constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to determine if a subclass implements a constructor from within a static method (in a base class)?

I'm trying to write a static `create` method (that acts like the `new` keyword) that by default works by passing attribute values as a properties object:

```
class Person extends Class {
    greet() { return 'hello from ' + this.name; }
}
var p = Person.create({name: 'world'};  // create a new Person object and set its `name` property to `'world'`
console.log(p.greet());  // => "hello from world"
```

but hands off to the class' constructor if it has one:

```
class Person2 extends Class {
    constructor(name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
    greet() { return 'hello from ' + this.name; }
}
var p = Person2.create('world');
console.log(p.greet());  // => "hello from world"
```

I'm stuck at finding out if the subclass defines its own constructor..

```
class Class {
    static create(...args) {
        let has_ctor = ??  // true iff the current subclass defines a constructor..

        if (has_ctor) {
            // let the constructor handle everything
            return new this(...args);
        } else {
            // assume that `args` contains exactly 1 pojo that defines instance variables to be overridden..
            var instance = new this();
            let props = args[0];
            for (let prop in props) instance[prop] = props[prop];
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

is this even possible?

Comment: Why not define a default constructor on `Class` that does this expansion? Then you could always do `return new this(...args);`?

Comment: because it would be too easy..?  ;-)   If you make  it an answer I can give you points..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it would be much easier to do

```
class Class {
    static create(...args) {
        // let the constructor handle everything
        return new this(...args);
    }
    constructor(props){
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }
}
```

then if things override the constructor, then can choose to pass props to `super()` or to assign them manually themselves.

Comment: Tip: Use `Object.assign` :-)

Comment: @Bergi Good call, copy/pasted from the question and never thought about it hahah.

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer your original question

> Is there a way to discover if a javascript 6 class defines its own constructor?

**No**, there is not. Every class does have its own constructor, because a "class" basically *is* just the constructor function.

If a class definition does not include a `constructor` method, then it is automatically supplied by the language (see [§14.5.14](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-classdefinitionevaluation)); either as

```
constructor(...args){ super (...args);}
```

if there is a super class or as

```
constructor(){ }
```

if there is none. The result is not distinguishable from a class where such a constructor was explicitly declared.